# {"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"} in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have tried using websocket instead of polling still the same error exists

A handshake request is sent to the server, the server responds with a SID and other information ({"sid":"f-re6ABU3Si4pmyWADCx","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000})
The client initiates a polling-request, including this SID: GET .../socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1408648886249-1&sid=f-re6ABU3Si4pmyWADCx
Instead of sending data, the server responds with 400 Bad Request: {"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}
The client performs a new handshake (GET .../socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1408648888050-3, notice the previously received SID is omitted)
The server responds with new connection data, including a new SID: ({"sid":"DdRxn2gv6vrtZOBiAEAS","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}

Comment: can anyone help me out regarding the issue Am still getting the same error {"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}

Comment: Try also tagging it with "java" to get more attention. IDK anything about Java, though.